# How to bind html elements with dynamically created ID to jQuery events in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview, renderpartial

I am iterating 3 times over a partial view in the Razor syntax. The code goes like this:

```
foreach(var item in Model.items) //Will be run 3 or more times
{
    {Html.RenderPartial("_viewname", item)}
}
```

Inside _viewname.cshtml, I am creating a table. Now I want to bind these tables to a jQuery Event, for which I am writing this:

```
$('#tbl tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
//Code goes here
});
```

Now the problem is that this event is getting called 3 times even when I click on any one of the table.

I want to somehow differentiate between the 3 tables. If I provide them different HTML ID's, then how should I write my jQuery code to capture it?

For example, _viewname.cshtml looks like this:

```
@model abc
<table id="tbl">
    //table body and other stuff
</table>
```

If I put id as "tbl_@Model.uniqueId", how to make sure that jQuery event is called.

P.S - There are other partial views within _viewname.cshtml, all of which should have uniquely identifiable ID.

Comment: ids should be unique in any case

Comment: Scripts do not go in partials (only the view or its layout). What makes you think you want them to have ID's?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Pete Just added the code of viewname.cshtml and the description. Let me know if that makes sense to you

Comment: read my comment, I don't think I need to expand on it

Comment: Replace your `id` with a class name (duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html) and then `$(this)` gives you the `<tr>`, and `$(this).closest('table')` gives you the table (and put the script in the view, not in the partial)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element that triggered the event by addidng a parameter to the function like:

```
$('#tbl tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
});
```

And then getting the target of the event

Comment: Yes, I can. But the problem is that this code will be called thrice, as now I have 3 tables with #tbl. And I don't know which one was clicked

Comment: You can get the element that triggered the event. So event.target should be the table that was clicked.